# DBRestClient requestDidLoadMetadata crashing in ios

Tags: ios, iphone

I am fetching list of files in background thread from Dropbox in my iOS app. Some times app is crashing. how can i resolve this crash please advise me. Thanks for advance.

```
 NSString *folderId = folderId;
 NSString *hash = hash;
 methodType = kGetFilesForMethodAllFiles;
 [[self restClient] loadMetadata:folderId withHash:hash];
```

How many number of folders are present in drop box account that many number of times this block of code  will execute.

---

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
SIGSEGV 0x0000000022015c88

Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x3802faf6 objc_msgSend + 21
1  GeekSquad                      0x3de107 -[DBRestClient requestDidLoadMetadata:] + 4694279
2  GeekSquad                      0x3dd411 -[DBRequest connection:didFailWithError:] + 4690961
3  CFNetwork                      0x25f51db9 __65-[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:]_block_invoke + 56
4  CFNetwork                      0x25f51d71 -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:] + 184
5  CFNetwork                      0x25f51e95 -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:] + 36
6  CFNetwork                      0x25f2db6d _NSURLConnectionDidFail(_CFURLConnection*, __CFError*, void const*) + 84
7  CFNetwork                      0x25ecd1eb   ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic17_delegate_didFailEP9__CFErrorU13block_pointerFvvE_block_invoke + 86
8  CFNetwork                      0x25ecba6b ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic18_withDelegateAsyncEPKcU13block_pointerFvP16_CFURLConnectionPK33CFURLConnectionClientCurrent_VMaxE_block_invoke_2 + 70
9  libdispatch.dylib              0x38747e1b _dispatch_client_callout + 22
10 libdispatch.dylib              0x3874f6b3 _dispatch_block_invoke + 450
11 CFNetwork                      0x25e02e8b RunloopBlockContext::_invoke_block(void const*, void*) + 18
12 CoreFoundation                 0x26507b19 CFArrayApplyFunction + 36
13 CFNetwork                      0x25e02d73 RunloopBlockContext::perform() + 182
14 CFNetwork                      0x25e02c3d MultiplexerSource::perform() + 216
15 CFNetwork                      0x25e02ad1 MultiplexerSource::_perform(void*) + 48
16 CoreFoundation                 0x265b77c7 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 14
17 CoreFoundation                 0x265b73b7 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 454
18 CoreFoundation                 0x265b571f __CFRunLoopRun + 806
19 CoreFoundation                 0x265080d9 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 516
20 CoreFoundation                 0x26507ecd CFRunLoopRunInMode + 108
21 GraphicsServices               0x2f83daf9 GSEventRunModal + 160
22 UIKit                          0x2a7912dd UIApplicationMain + 144
23 GeekSquad                      0xd8db main (main.m:37)
24 libdyld.dylib                  0x38770873 start + 2
```

Comment: Could you please add a little code in order to understand what's going wrong. And a little more explaination is more than welcome too...

Comment: HI Abarisone, I am added some code. This block of code will execute in background thread. this is working for 2GB fulled accounts. in case of more than 20GB fulled accounts app is crashing